# Tweepy not returning the given amount of tweets

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have the following code

```py
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

```py
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                            tweet_mode="extended",
                            q=query + " exclude:retweets").items(11000):
    hashtags = "#" + " #".join([hashtag['text'] for hashtag in tweet.entities.get('hashtags')])
    print(i)

    if tweet.place:
        tweet_place = tweet.place.full_name + ', ' + tweet.place.country_code
    else:
        tweet_place = "Not Geo-tagged"
    i += 1
    
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.id, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8'), tweet.created_at, tweet.lang, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count, tweet_place, tweet.user.id, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.user.followers_count, tweet.user.friends_count, tweet.user.created_at, tweet.user.favourites_count, tweet.user.statuses_count, tweet.user.lang, tweet.user.verified, tweet.user.location])
```

I am trying to get 11000 tweets with a specific search query but after some time it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .............
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  .............
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  .............
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  .............
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Earlier it was happening around 2500 tweets but on changing the query it started happening at around 5000 tweets. Any idea what can be wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

its most likely because you have exceeded the allowed amount of tweets that you can pull at once / per 15 minutes

check [here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes but i think it paused for that time and resumed again. At around 2500 tweets it paused for quite some time and then resumed maybe because of `wait_on_rate_limit=True`
But still it was strange as this error appeared only around 2500 and 5000 tweets

Comment: try fetching like 500 tweets multiple times instead of grabbing all 10k tweets at once

Comment: but that way it is possible that I get repeated tweets. Or is there any way you'd suggest to get unique tweets in each cycle of 500?

Comment: What is your expectation of the Twitter API here? You can make repeated requests (within a rate limit) and pages of up to 100 requests at a time. Why do you think that you can request 11000 Tweets in a single piece of code?

Comment: According to what I know, if I make repeated requests it is highly likely that I get repeated tweets, whereas I wanted 11000 unique tweets. Just getting all the tweets different is my main concern

Comment: you could get the id of the last tweet you got in every iteration and start from that id , i know it works with user time line but idk about Cursor

Comment: @MoeAbuShaqra could you elaborate a bit more? as my search query is something like `#hashtag exclude:retweets` so not sure how this can be done

Comment: you could do something similar to https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496 , but since this goes through tweets in someones timeline , they are ordered.